# Flutter: The current Flutter SDK version is 0.0.0-unknown

Tags: flutter

This is an error that you might have seen in multiple questions.
I tried to get rid of it but it is still not working.

This is the error.

```
Running "flutter pub get" in testapp...                  
The current Flutter SDK version is 0.0.0-unknown.

Because qr_code_scanner 0.0.13 requires Flutter SDK version ^1.10.0 and no versions of qr_code_scanner match >0.0.13 <0.1.0, qr_code_scanner ^0.0.13 is forbidden.

So, because testapp depends on qr_code_scanner ^0.0.13, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because testapp depends on qr_code_scanner ^0.0.13, version solving failed.)
exit code 1
```

Till yesterday it was working fine but today I restarted my Mac and then it started giving me the error. I tried `flutter clean` and `flutter update` also tried some other suggestions which I found from GitHub and SO. I deleted the bin directory and downloading the stable release but it is still giving me error in VS Code.

Flutter Doctor is looking ok to me.

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.4, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H2 darwin-x64, locale
    en-IN)
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[✗] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    ✗ Xcode installation is incomplete; a full installation is necessary for iOS
      development.
      Download at: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/
      Or install Xcode via the App Store.
      Once installed, run:
        sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
        sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
    ✗ CocoaPods not installed.
        CocoaPods is used to retrieve the iOS and macOS platform side's plugin
        code that responds to your plugin usage on the Dart side.
        Without CocoaPods, plugins will not work on iOS or macOS.
        For more info, see https://flutter.dev/platform-plugins
      To install:
        sudo gem install cocoapods
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.1)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.51.1)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

I am only working for Android at the moment. So, Xcode error can be ignored.

### Edit

In another question I found that pubspec.lock has the wrong version of Flutter.

```
  flutter:
    dependency: "direct main"
    description: flutter
    source: sdk
    version: "0.0.0"
```

I deleted this file and run `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` but the newly generated file is also having the same details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a couple of things to resolve this error. If you find any other solution please add that in the answer.

`Flutter Doctor` - to verify things are OK or not.

`which flutter` - to get the path of flutter. FYI I am using Mac OS.

`vscode (plugins for dart flutter etc)` - Just verify all plugins are in running state or not. One time my flutter plugin was not in running state and one instance I found to-do plugin is not running. I restarted the plugins and it is working properly.

`Flutter clean` and delete the .packages folder

```
Flutter pub get
```

Try to build the apk from command line (command or cmd), not from IDE like VS Code.

```
flutter build apk
```

If this is working then the problem was with your IDE.

Just run the app from VS Code (IDE). Most of the time this resolved my issues.

Note - I have shared the things which I found was working on my machine. I am not sure these are the correct steps to resolve the issue or not. Because I have seen many SO questions and Git issues but not all are fixing the issue. Maybe it is related to device to device or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Probably an under the hood compatibility issue with the new flutter sdk updates. I saw the package you were trying to use hasn't been updated since May. It's probably time to move on. I would switch to a project that is more up to date like **qrscan** https://pub.dev/packages/qrscan

Comment: Thanks Petro. I will also move on no issues from that front. But first i need to get this one fixed.

Comment: Try a flutter clean and restart/invalidate caches. If that doesn't work switch versions down to 0.0.12. Or try another Flutter SDK version like 1.10

Comment: i changed the package to qrscan and tried but error is still there.

Comment: did you remove the old entry from `pubspace.yaml`?

Comment: yes i did. created a new project and that was working fine. so it means something is wrong with this project.

Comment: I would try manually deleting the `/build` folder

Answer (score 0):

1. go to your downloads folder and there you can find flutter sdk folder(if you not deleted from downloads),and from there copy the packed-refs and config file[follow the path mentioned in the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Nc2K.jpg)

2. then go to the existing sdk location and delete those two files(packed-refs and config file) and then paste the the folder which we copied earlier.
3. in android studio click get dependencies button or manullay pub get.
4. Then app will run succesfully

Answer (score 0):

I tried everything 1.installing new flutter, upgrading etc...

didn't work out but...

I had to switch off my system and put it back on.
This was after several processes above was carried out...

probably there was a need to put the system off after re-installing flutter sdk.  And then using pub get works now.....

Though what caused it has not been known yet....I use MAC-OS

Answer (score -1):

Go to your Windows Flutter path and delete it

system -> advanced system -> system properties -> ambient variable -> variable system -> path -> click -> delete flutter location

delete flutter folder

go to cmd  admin

cd..
cd..
cd..
cd..
cd..
cd..
cd..
mkdir something
cd something
download flutter
https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows
git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git -b stable

again go to path
system -> advanced system -> system properties -> ambient variable -> variable system -> path -> click -> delete flutter location

new..
add
C:\something\flutter\bin
C:\Program Files\Git\bin\
C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\
save
save
done
close cmd
open cmd admin
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/64699
flutter channel stable
flutter doctor